# JQ: filter nested array of objects in only include selected fields

Tags: json, jq, github-cli

Starting with the following, I just want the .title, .url, .author.login, .reviews.author.login, .reviews.state and .mergedBy.login fields? I'm getting close with `map({ title: .title, URL: .url, author: .author.login, reviews: .reviews, "merged by": .mergedBy.login})` but how do I also limit the fields in the reviews array to author.login and state?

```
[
  {
    "author": {
      "id": "MDQ6VXNlcjYGJOYzNTIw",
      "is_bot": false,
      "login": "luke123",
      "name": "Luke"
    },
    "mergedAt": "2023-01-12T20:29:41Z",
    "mergedBy": {
      "id": "MDQ6VXNlcjYGJOYzNTIw",
      "is_bot": false,
      "login": "luke123",
      "name": "Luke"
    },
    "reviews": [
      {
        "id": "PRR_kwDODrt9D55KSvlh",
        "author": {
          "login": "han123"
        },
        "authorAssociation": "CONTRIBUTOR",
        "body": "",
        "submittedAt": "2023-01-12T20:26:50Z",
        "includesCreatedEdit": false,
        "reactionGroups": [],
        "state": "APPROVED",
        "commit": {
          "oid": "ff541b49775eab1ffc63www850dc405ecabc045f"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "PRR_kwDODrt7OM8WHwat",
        "author": {
          "login": "leia"
        },
        "authorAssociation": "CONTRIBUTOR",
        "body": "",
        "submittedAt": "2023-01-12T20:29:15Z",
        "includesCreatedEdit": false,
        "reactionGroups": [],
        "state": "APPROVED",
        "commit": {
          "oid": "dd541b49775eab1ffc63bbb850dc405edhwc045c"
        }
      }
    ],
    "title": "Jedi Training",
    "url": "https://github.com/rebels/training/pull/222"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines, or at least clarify whether you want the structure to be preserved.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input! My command became alot bigger when trying to convert to csv but I got there.

Answer (score 2):

One of many possibilities for preserving the structure:

```
…, reviews: (.reviews | map({author,state} | .author|= {login})) …
```

The technique of writing {foo} as an abbreviation for {"foo": .foo} comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same technique with `map({…})` as you did on the outer object:

```bash
map({
  title,
  URL: .url,
  author: .author.login,
  reviews: (.reviews | map({
    author: .author.login,
    state
  })),
  "merged by": .mergedBy.login
})
```

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Jedi Training",
    "URL": "https://github.com/rebels/training/pull/222",
    "author": "luke123",
    "reviews": [
      {
        "author": "han123",
        "state": "APPROVED"
      },
      {
        "author": "leia",
        "state": "APPROVED"
      }
    ],
    "merged by": "luke123"
  }
]
```

Note: To just replicate a field, e.g. `{title: .title}`, you can shorten it to just `{title}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily nest `map` calls. Just make sure that you group value expressions with a pipe:

```
map({
    title,
    URL: .url,
    author: .author.login,
    reviews: (.reviews | map({"reviewed by": .author.login, state})),
    "merged by": .mergedBy.login
})
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Jedi Training",
    "URL": "https://github.com/rebels/training/pull/222",
    "author": "luke123",
    "reviews": [
      {
        "reviewed by": "han123",
        "state": "APPROVED"
      },
      {
        "reviewed by": "leia",
        "state": "APPROVED"
      }
    ],
    "merged by": "luke123"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `.reviews` you say: Take the complete `reviews` data and reuse it.

Similar to what you are doing for the complete list you could also map that array and only extract the required data for each entry:

`jq 'map({ title: .title, URL: .url, author: .author.login, reviews: .reviews | map({ author: .author.login, state: .state }), "merged by": .mergedBy.login})'`

The pipe operator `|` allows you to apply a filter to the result of the `.reviews` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to extract the required data:

```
jq '[.[] |
    {
      title: .title,
      URL: .url,
      author: .author.login,
      reviews: [.reviews[] | {
        "author": .author.login,
        "state": .state
      }],
      "merged by": .mergedBy.login
    }
  ]' data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting off with your own solution, restricting all nests within "reviews" to two keys - "author" and "state" - and finally, setting "author" to .author.login

```
map({ 
  title: .title, 
  URL: .url, 
  author: .author.login, 
  reviews: [(.reviews[] | with_entries(select(.key == "author" or .key == "state")) | .author=.author.login)], 
  "merged by": .mergedBy.login
})
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Jedi Training",
    "URL": "https://github.com/rebels/training/pull/222",
    "author": "luke123",
    "reviews": [
      {
        "author": "han123",
        "state": "APPROVED"
      },
      {
        "author": "leia",
        "state": "APPROVED"
      }
    ],
    "merged by": "luke123"
  }
]
```